# What may be the appropriate encoding method when I want to save the sensor data with two decimals in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: compression, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I currently saved the sensor data in Apache IoTDB with two decimal places, so is it suitable to use the encoding method run-length encoding (RLE) to compress the data? Also, if neither the encoding method (`ENCODING` field) nor the compression method (`COMPRESSOR` field) is specified, are there any compression effective in Apache IoTDB? What method will be used by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default result format of RLE is 2 decimal places in Apache IoTDB, so that's fine for your case.
If neither the encoding method nor the compression method is specified, the default PLAIN encoding compression will be used in IoTDB.